# scipy.fft hangs with certain sound files

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

`scipy.fft` seems to hang when running this simple script:

```
import scipy
from scipy.io import wavfile

sound = 'sounds/silence/iPhone5.wav'
fs, data = wavfile.read(sound)
print scipy.fft(data)
```

on certain files. Try [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mh3h6jzqv1exzmf/iPhone5.wav) file for example.

A few things I noticed:

1. Running the individual commands from the interactive interpreter does not hang.
2. Running with other sound files does not always hang the script (it's not just this file that isn't working though)
3. Sometimes I get *WavFileWarning: chunk not understood*, but it doesn't seem to be related to when it happens
4. If I terminate the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I get the result as if it never got stuck.
5. Opening the file with `wave` or `audiolab` leads to the same result.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check the value of `data.shape` for the files that hang up the system. If your data length happens to be a prime number, or the product of several large prime numbers, there isn't much that the FFT algorithm can do to speed up calculation of the DFT. If you pad with zeros, or trim your data to the nearest power of 2, everything should run much, much faster.

Comment: Spot on, thank you. The result I was getting when Ctrl+C'ing the terminal was not the correct one, but probably whatever it had reached by that point in the calculation. If you would like to convert your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of data.shape for the files that hang up the system. If your data length happens to be a prime number, or the product of several large prime numbers, there isn't much that the FFT algorithm can do to speed up calculation of the DFT. If you pad with zeros, or trim your data to the nearest power of 2, everything should run much, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This should have been a comment, but there's just not enough space there...

You could do a bit more debugging, which might help a bit.
(Assuming you're on some sort of unix-like OS)

1. When the program gets stuck, does it idle or use a lot of CPU? You could use "top" or similar to check.
2. What is the program doing when it appears stuck? Can you get a stack trace? Either using a debugger like gdb or some other tool.
3. And I guess what really should be step one. Search the net for your symptoms. If it is a bug, it is likely already found and reported. It might even be fixed already.

By looking at a stack trace it should be possible to see if the program is stuck waiting for something, stuck in a loop somewhere or just doing lots of work. 
It might also be able to tell you if the problem is in python code, C extensions or somewhere else. Being used to read stack traces is of course a plus. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. The process does take a lot of CPU when it's stuck on that like, but there is no stack trace -- it doesn't throw any error. If I Ctrl+C-break it, it just outputs the *correct* result. Running through pdb didn't provide any better insight -- still stuck on the same line. Googleing was, of course, the first thing I've done.